# Прокрутка страницы + слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

[image: Пример]

Здрасти)
Как реализовать слайдер, который при прокрутки сайте будет фиксировать экран и полностью прокручиваться до последнего элемента, и после этого отпустит экран.
Вот пример работы - https://teamway.io

Comment: Судя по ползунку прокрутки, ничего там не фиксируется, просто в каком-то диапазоне position: fixed выставляется. В этом диапазоне страницы другого контента нет. А также соразмерно scroll-y горизонтальная прокрутка делается.

Comment: Все гораздо хуже. `Position: sticky`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам по себе `sticky` работает так: он становится фиксировано позиционированным, пока его родитель в области окна просмотра. То есть родитель должен быть больше по высоте и вхолостую прокручиваться. Останется только горизонтальная прокрутка уже с помощью JS.

```css
#sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1220px">
  Прокрутите вниз, пожалуйста!
    <div style="background: grey; height: 800px; margin-top: 200px">
        <div id="sticky" style="background: black; height: 160px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```